# How to handle multiple buttons tapped down simultaneously In React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to create a controller for a robot for which it must **handle multiple button tap events simultaneously**
The Buttons are supposed to be **Tapped Down and hold which would send repeated Commands** to the robot on a timer.

```
  <TouchableOpacity
    activeOpacity={0.4}
    {...otherProps}
    delayPressOut={100}
    onPressIn={onPressIn}
    onPressOut={onPressOut}>
    {children}
  </TouchableOpacity>
```

There are multiple buttons That uses this component

I Have tried

> onTouchStart={onPressIn} and onTouchEnd={onPressOut}

but when using this the second button is not triggered

Similar to this issue
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21912

Comment: Just curious, have you tried with Pressable or TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler?

Answer (score 0):

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Found the Solution